# How to copy two files in expect script?

Tags: bash, expect

please advice why

```
spawn  scp  $FILE1   $FILE2  $LOGIN@$IP:/tmp
```

in my expect script copy only FILE1 and not copy FILE2 ?

I try to to transfer both files by scp  as

```
 scp file1.csv file2.crt 192.8.200.1:/tmp
```

without expect  and they transferred successfully to /tmp

so why VIA expect the only file that copied is **FILE1** ??

what wrong in my syntax ?

example of my expect script:

```
 #!/usr/bin/expect -f
 set FILE1  file1.csv
 set FILE2  file2.crt
 set multiPrompt {[#>$]}
 spawn  scp  $FILE1   $FILE2  $LOGIN@$IP:/tmp
           expect {
                     ")?"   { send "yes\r"  ; exp_continue  }

                    word:  {send $PASS\r}
                   }
```

I also try this:

```
spawn  scp  "$FILE1   $FILE2"   $LOGIN@$IP:/tmp
```

OR

```
spawn  scp  '$FILE1   $FILE2'   $LOGIN@$IP:/tmp
```

but I get the same problem

Comment: Note that, by default, expect's patterns are glob patterns (documented in [string match](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm#M39)), so `")?"` means "match a close parenthesis followed by **any character**". Is this what you're intending to match? While you're developing your script, add `exp_internal 1` as the first line following the shebang.

Comment: You definitely do not want to put quotes around `$FILE1 $FILE2`

Comment: You don't declare any of LOGIN, PASS, IP in your script. Where do those values come from?

Comment: I tried the same thing and it worked for me:

    #!/usr/bin/expect
    set FILE1 foo
    set FILE2 bar
    spawn scp $FILE1 $FILE2 root@127.0.0.1:/tmp
    expect {
         "Password:" { send "password\r"}
    }
    expect {
        "\n" {}
    }

Try a simpler command like `echo` maybe?  What does it print when it runs; `spawn` prints its invocation?

Comment: You can use the `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` scp option to avoid the first query you're trying to match on and answer ("`)?`").  Any `expect` exchange you can avoid will make your script more reliable.  What happens if you add the `-v` option to `scp`?  Have you tried changing `scp` to `/usr/bin/scp` just to be paranoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written the following `expect` script for this, and it works (on my vms).
Sample run:

```
./scp.exp <first host user> <first host user pass> <first host name> <second host name> <second host user> <second host user pass> <directory path i.e. /tmp>
```

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
# ./sshlogin.exp uptime
# set Variables

set user [lindex $argv 0];
set password [lindex $argv 1];
set host [lindex $argv 2];
set copy_to_host [lindex $argv 3];
set copy_to_host_user [lindex $argv 4];
set copy_to_host_pass [lindex $argv 5];
set copy_to_host_dir [lindex $argv 6];
set file1 one.txt;
set file2 two.txt;
set timeout 10
# now ssh
spawn ssh $user@$host -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
match_max 100000 # Look for passwod prompt
expect "*?assword:*"
# Send password aka $password
send -- "$password\r"
# send blank line (\r) to make sure we get back to gui
expect "*$ "
send -- "scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $file1 $file2 $copy_to_host_user@$copy_to_host:$copy_to_host_dir\r"
expect "*?assword:*"
send -- "$copy_to_host_pass\r"
expect "*$ " 
send -- "exit\r"
expect eof
```

Note: you might need to add some wait time to `expect` if dealing with large files.